# How to stop videos from being downloaded from my website

Tags: security, flash, video-streaming

I have an online class website where I have put videos for different courses. Users can view the videos, but I want them to be unable to download the videos by any means (e.g using any third party software or by copying the video link). How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Amazon Elastic Transcoder to transcode your videos to HLS(HTTP Live Streaming). HLS use segments of the encrypted video from s3. This will prevent downloading of videos from s3.

https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

Answer (score 1):

HLS wont make it impossible to download video, it's just going to make it harder to download, infact it's impossible to disable downloading. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hls-downloader/apomkbibleomoihlhhdbeghnfioffbej?hl=en